# How to fetch Daily Top Score from GameCenter in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-center, leaderboard

I am trying to fetch the daily top scorer's of the game from Game center. I can get All-time top player's score by using this code snippet.

```
Social.LoadScores ("leaderboard_id",scores => {
        if(scores.Length > 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Got " + scores.Length + " scores");
            string myScores = "Leaderboard:\n";
            foreach (IScore score in scores)
            myScores += "AllTime" + "\t" + score.userID + " " + score.formattedValue + " " + score.date + "\n"+ " "+score.rank;
            Debug.Log(myScores);
        }
```

Well in android this snippet is fetching almost top 25 players for an API call. But in iOS it's only giving top 1 player score and one more thing I couldn't find anything for fetching the daily top score, even though by default its giving all-time top player score. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612915/how-to-fetch-top-10-scores-from-a-specific-gamecenter-leaderboard-with-swift-io

Comment: @Draco18s Nope. This is Unity. OP should tag C# next time

Comment: @Programmer There may still be a similar field in the Unity wrapper.  When compiled, both Swift and Unity are calling the same native code.  That's why I said *related* not *duplicate.*

Answer (score 2):

In Unity 5.6 you can do:

```
 void ShowScoresForToday()
 {
     // OutputField is a Unity text element I'm using to debug this on the device
     OutputField.text = "";

     var leaderboardID = "leaderboard";
     var log = string.Format( "Top score for leaderboard with id: '{0}'", leaderboardID );
     Debug.Log( log );
     OutputField.text = log;

     var leaderboard = Social.CreateLeaderboard();
     leaderboard.id = leaderboardID;
     leaderboard.timeScope = TimeScope.Today;
     leaderboard.LoadScores( success =>
     {
         var scores = leaderboard.scores;
         if ( scores.Length > 0 )
         {
            foreach ( var score in scores )
            {
                var logLine = string.Format( "User: '{0}'; Score: {1}; Rank: {2}",
                    score.userID, score.value, score.rank );
                OutputField.text += "\n" + logLine;
            }
         }
         else
         {
             Debug.LogError( "No scores registered" );
         }
     } );
 }
```

You have to initialize the Leaderboard object before querying, with the Social.CreateLeaderboard()

Other filters are, hm, limited - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SocialPlatforms.ILeaderboard.html

Would be fun to be able to query specific date ranges, but no.

I would assume that you can't because of how GameCenter itself stores these scores - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH7-SW30

EDIT: @CharlieSeligman, you asked me about getting the username after you have the userID:

```
Social.LoadScores( leaderboardID, scores =>
{
    var log = string.Format( "There are {0} players in the leaderboard", scores.Length );
    Debug.Log( log );

    var userIDs = new List<string>();
    foreach ( var score in scores )
    {
        var idLog = string.Format( "User with id '{0}' and scored {1}, rank is {2}",
            score, score.value, score.rank );
        Debug.Log( idLog );
        userIDs.Add( score.userID );
    }

    Social.LoadUsers( userIDs.Distinct().ToArray(), userProfiles =>
    {
        var user = userProfiles[0];
        var usernameLog = string.Format( "User with id '{0}' is {1}",
            user.id, user.userName );
        Debug.Log( usernameLog );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Is there a way of getting the gamecenter player name?  the userID value returns a unique id but not their actual player name in GameCenter

Comment: Thanks Abel - that is very kind!